# How to handle "mailto:" and "tel:" links in Android webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have indeed checked all the suggested solutions, but keep getting the activity error if I try to implement them. So here is a very specific question. I have a webview in my app that is showing the site: "https://ikeen.com", in the header I have "mailto:" and "tel:" links, currently if I open them from an app I get an error like cannot find the page. How to invoke the behaviour similar to the webpage, i.e. open dialer or email client.

Here is my code. Please forgive me if I would sound lame, this is my first try at java/android.

```
package com.ikeen.ikeenapp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    // Для старых устройств
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Currently all other links except for tel and mailto are working. Again really sorry for this question, I just could not understand solutions in other questions here, as I could not understand the activity part there. Thanks.

Comment: For mailto: you should use ACTION_SEND using the privided email address.

Comment: I'm totally new to java/android, can you show me an example using my code? Thanks for effort.

Comment: Can you help me on that error?
error: method startActivity in class ContextCompat cannot be applied to given types;
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri));
            ^
  required: Context,Intent,Bundle
  found: Intent
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @blackapps I was not lazy, I understood that getting intents is too early for me, so I just moved everything to MainActivity class and it worked. Thanks for your time anyway. It is just way to early for me now to understand how Contexts work and Intents, I think I will get it in about 1 month time.

Comment: Good you found it yourself. Thats what i hoped you would do.